# Replace parent tag with first child HTML in VisualStudio Editor

Tags: html, visual-studio, resharper

Iam looking for possible solution to my problem. Lets say I got this html

```
<a>
  <td>
  </td>
<a/>
```

I see that I made mistake and I want to somehow move `a` tag to be one of the child elements of `td`. The result should look like this

```
<td>
   <a>
   </a>
<td/>
```

My question is that, is there any macro, extension or something to make it work? For example Resharper only suggest me to delete parent tag and promote children. The best solution for me it would be using Alt + arrows so the selected tag moves between other tags instead of moving only single line with tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. You can use ReSharper's rearrange code feature (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> and the cursor keys) to move tags around. You can use up and down to move a tag (and child tags) above and below the tags that are above and below the current line. You can also use left and right to move a tag into and out of the scope of the current tag.

So you could put the caret on the `<td>` of the first example above, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and it will move the whole `<td></td>` block outside of the scope of the `<a>` block. Hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> will push it into the `<a>` block, making it a child again.

However, when you move a tag out of scope, it doesn't swap to become the parent of the original scoping tag, but a sibling, so you can't easily get what you're after, sadly. Other languages have support for a feature called "greedy brace", which would be ideal here - instead of moving a whole block, you move the closing brace of a statement (such as an `if` statement) and it extends the contents of the block. Ideally, HTML would also support this - you could use "greedy brace" on the closing tag angle bracket and it would allow moving just the closing tag to encompass sibling tags as children. I've added a feature request you can vote on, track and add any extra details to: [RSRP-450292](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450292).

Comment: That helps a little as I didnt know about this resharper shortcout, although it would be nice to have this greedy brace. I will +1 this feature request.